# Android WebView displayed on only half screen

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-webview

My web view displayed well without any problem. However, after I apply "Selected Text" function, the web view is then shown on only a half of the screen (see the image below).

[image]

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    setContentView(R.layout.content);

    Intent i = this.getIntent();

    final int wordId = i.getIntExtra("id", -1);
    mCurrentWord = i.getStringExtra("word");
    mSelectedDB = i.getStringExtra("db");
    mContentStyle = i.getStringExtra("style");

    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

    loadHistoryFromPreferences();
    loadFavouriteFromPreferences();

    wvContent = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvContent);
    initWebview();
    String content = getContentById(wordId);
    showContent(content);

    //This is the beginning of what I added
    webkit=new Webkit(this);
    wvContent.addView(webkit);
    WebkitSelectedText webkitSelectedText=new WebkitSelectedText(getApplicationContext(), webkit);
    webkitSelectedText.init();

    wvContent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {           
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    //This is the end of what I added
```

I have no idea what I have done wrongly. Except this display problem, all other functions including new added one `Selected text` work just fine.

I hope you guys could realise the problem and do me a favour to fix it. Thank you very much.

**EDITED**

Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="bottom|fill_vertical"
>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android=
    "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >       
    <WebView  
        android:id="@+id/wvContent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top" 
        android:layout_weight="1"  
    />

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnHome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/home"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
    />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnPronounce"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/pronounce"
        android:layout_weight="0.25" 
    />      
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnShowHistory"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/history"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
    /> 
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnAddFavourite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/add_favourite"
        android:layout_weight="0.25" 
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be with the layout.

In content.xml in res/layout, make sure you set the properties of webview's android:layout_height to fill_parent.

That should fix. It not, paste the contents of the layout too. And we can help

Comment: Thanks, I already set them to "fill_parent". But please have a look at my layout in EDITED.

Comment: So, does anyone figure the problem out? Please have a look to help.

Comment: Remove this from the parent Linear layout   android:gravity="bottom|fill_vertical"

Comment: Thanks, but removing `android:gravity="bottom|fill_vertical"` does not help, either.

Comment: One more issue in your file..you should not be using namespace twice!! Delete this xmlns:android=
    "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  Use it only in parent

Comment: Thanks, I think the problem lies somewhere else rather than in the layout (things had been all fine before the new code was added). By the way, I notice one out of five times the web view displays normally, i.e the text is shown normally on the full screen. What a headache!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this may help guys with similar problem or not, but in the end I solve my problem by changing:

```
wvContent.addView(webkit);
```

to

```
wvContent.addView(webkit,0,0);
```

Not really a solution but a workaround, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem and think I fixed it with the following code in the WebViewClient:

```
webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

My issue was that it only displayed half screen on first load, as soon as I clicked on a menu or changed the orientation of the device, the view was re-drawn at full screen.  setting it to Visible seemed to trigger a re-draw that fixe